# Insert into another table with relation

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have two tables

1.table

```
Login_user

user_id  username password
1        Noor     1233 
2        Sara     122334
```

2.table

```
post_user
post_id user_id title text 
1         1     xxx   xxx
2         2     vvv   bbb
```

How can i know the user_id that logged in and insert it in the post_id table ...
to know how the user that posted..
how should the query should be ...
i tried this query

```
INSERT INTO Post (title,text,user_id) VALUES 
        ('${title}','${text}','(SELECT Users.users_id FROM Users  )')
```

Comment: does the user_id is a foreign key to the user table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the query should be something like this:

```
insert into posts (title, text, user_id) values (`${title}`, `${text}`, `${user_id}`);
```

and this `(SELECT Users.users_id FROM Users  )` will be placed with list of user ids and eventually will through an error

and you don't wanna that instead just place the user_id who did created the post to keep your data consistent and relevant to the user who did the actions

Comment: First i made post to login and in another function i made post to post_user

Comment: Your query dose not work the error is >>>>>users_id is not defined

Comment: so you have to store the logged in user on the app first and them use the user id with any post action related to the user,however you must be using some kind of authentication model ,if so the request already must be distinguishable from witch user? isn't it now?